# Same custom button on 2 totaly different lists

Tags: list, ribbon, list-definition

Is it possible to have just the same custom button,  show on 2 totaly different lits?

Because when i use the same type for the lists TemplateType="10777" then the list have the same fields.
So i need to have different templates for the lists, but in the custom button i can only add one RegistrationId="10777" right? Or is it somehow possible to combine or ..?

So to explain a bit
I have 2 different list definitions, which have different fields defined in a schema, all of them to use same button i had to add templatetype 10777, but if i choose different types it is ok, the lists are different, but the button will only appear on the type = 10777 so do i need to create an other button?

I think there should be a way to solve this without creating the same button .. for other list, but im not sure?